# Failed to resolve symbol 'operator delete[]'

Tags: c++

I'm trying a simple exercise where I am allocating memory for an array of 10 integers held within a struct data type. I managed to allocate the memory and populate the array. I tested this by outputting their values and addresses. The problem is that once I tried to de-allocate the memory I got the error message:

Failed to resolve symbol 'operator delete[]' because it is defined in an object in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x86\MSVCRTD.lib' that has not been loaded.

It also lists the filepath to the visual studio project in parenthesis afterwards.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct structTwo {
int* numbers;
};

int main() {

structTwo myStruct;
myStruct.numbers = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

    *(myStruct.numbers + i) = i;
    cout << *(myStruct.numbers + i) << " at " << myStruct.numbers + i 
    << endl;
}

delete[] myStruct.numbers;

return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what this means? Am I missing an inclusion statement?

Comment: You are not missing an include statement. I've seen similar errors (though not exactly the same) when different types of libraries get mixed up in configuration (for example, compiled with MT runtime and MD runtime). It's not a problem with the code you are showing.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `*(myStruct.numbers + i)` is usually written as `myStruct.numbers[i]`. They both do the same thing, but the latter is clearer.